# Excel: Total Time in Days, Hours, Minutes

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, formula, days

I need to get a total time in the greyed out box on my form.  Image includes formula for your reference. What I have entered is not computing anything.

[image: Total Time Relief Record]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not total the strings, instead do an array type formula like:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(B2:B11-A2:A11,0))
```

To get the value.

[image]

Then in your formula replace all the `H10:H27` with `SUM(IFERROR(F10:F27-D10:D27,0))`

so:

```
=INT(SUM(IFERROR(F10:F27-D10:D27,0)))&" Days "&HOUR(MOD(SUM(IFERROR(F10:F27-D10:D27,0)),1))&" Hrs "&MINUTE(MOD(SUM(IFERROR(F10:F27-D10:D27,0)),1))&" Mins"
```

Depending one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thank you so very much for going out of your way to answer this.  I've updated the formula to what you've provided and it is saying, "Alert.  You've entered too few arguments for this function."

Comment: @W_Lemon that is what I get for typing freehand.  see edit.

Comment: It worked! Oh my gosh, Scott...I can't tell you how grateful I am!  Thank you! I have spent weeks trying to teach myself Excel formulas.  You've been a tremendous help. Bless you!

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.